# Asp.Net Core и Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-core

Народ! нужна помощь, нужно сделать две фичи! Like и Комент через ajax на Asp.Net Core.

Есть класс Post:

```
public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Изображение")]
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Описание")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Нравиться!")]
        public int Like { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Количество комментариев")]
        public int ComentCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Есть класс Comment

```
public class Comment
    {
        [Key] public string CommentId { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public string PostId { get; set; }
        public Publication Post { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }

    }
```

Вот кнопка во вьюшке

```
<input id="LikeId" type="submit" value="Like" class="btn btn-default" />
```

которая по задумки должна делать like

так же есть форма для комента

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Post)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CommentDate)
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <textarea></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="PostId" value="@item.PostId" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="UserId" value="0" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <td>
```

не могу реализовать логику для Like и Коментов.

Для комментариев пробовал делать так:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Comment(string publicationId, int applicationUserId, string content)
        {
            Comment comment = new Comment();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                comment.UserId = applicationUserId;
                comment.PostId = publicationId;
                comment.CommentDate = DateTime.Now;
                comment.Content = content;

                _context.Add(comment);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(comment);

        }
```

Но не работает.

Ajax Пробовал так для комента:

```
<input id="LikeId" type="submit" value="Like" class="btn btn-default" />

<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Comments" asp-action="Index" title="Comment">Оставить комментарий</a>

<hr />

<div>
        Комментарии (@Model.ComentCount)<br/>
        <a onclick="openCommentForm(@Model.Id)" style="cursor: pointer">Оставить комментарий</a>
    </div>
    <div id="postdiv-@Model.Id" style="display:none">
        <textarea id="posttext-@Model.Id"></textarea>
        <input type="button" id="postComment" onclick="sendComment('@Model.Id', '@Model.Description')" value="Отправить"/>
    </div>

    @section Scripts{
        <script>
            function openCommentForm(publicationId) {
                $('#postdiv-' + publicationId).show();
            }

            function sendComment(publicationId, applicationUserId) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Comment", "Comments")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { 'publicationId': publicationId, 'ApplicationUserId': applicationUserId, 'content': $('#posttext-' + publicationId).val() },
                    success: console.log('все ок'),
                    error: console.log('Ошибка во время отправки комментария')
                });
            }


        </script>
    }
```

Пример с которого делал:

```
<div>
        Комментарии (@post.CommentsCount)<br/>
        <a onclick="openCommentForm(@post.Id)" style="cursor: pointer">Оставить комментарий</a>
    </div>
    <div id="postdiv-@post.Id" style="display:none">
        <textarea id="posttext-@post.Id"></textarea>
        <input type="button" id="postComment" onclick="sendComment('@post.Id', '@Model.User.Id')" value="Отправить"/>
    </div>


function openCommentForm(postId) {            
            $('#postdiv-' + postId).show();
        }


function sendComment(postId, userId) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Comment", "Post")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'postId': postId, 'userId': userId, 'content': $('#posttext-' + postId).val() },
                success: console.log('все ок'),
                error: console.log('Ошибка во время отправки комментария')
            });
        }
```

модель:

```
public class Comment
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }

        public string PostId { get; set; }
        public User Post { get; set; }

        public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: У вас в коде нет ни формы, ни javascript кода, ни ajax вызовов. Неудивительно, что не работает

Comment: @tym32167 ну так в это и проблема! Не пойму как всё это друг с другом законектить. А, так как  ajax не пробовал раньше вообще, запутался. С логикой методов, тоже не как недодумаюсь как реализовать особенно like. Вроде всё просто должно быть но не как не пойму.

Comment: Ну а в чем проблема то? Вы не знаете как ajax запрос отправить? Или у вас с бекендом проблема? Или что не получается то? Когда вы задаете вопрос, пишите что вы пытались, покажите код, которым вы пробовали отправить запрос, расскажите что не получилось. У вас же ничего этого нет в вопросе, вы просто накидали что то, что к ajax отношения не имеет

Comment: Для ajax запроса достаточно иметь: HTML+ javascript на клиенте, 1 действие в контроллере и 1 модель на сервере. Вы собрались отправлять лайки, значит должна быть модель лайка, контроллер с методом для лайка, HTML разметка для лайка и javascript код для отправки ajax  запроса. Что из этого у вас есть? Я ничего такого в вопросе не вижу

Comment: @tym32167 Обновил! Добавил что пробовал с ajax. Для лайка думал использовать свойство Like из Post.

Comment: вижу, что javascript для ajax запроса для комментария у вас уже есть. Какие проблемы написать подобное для лайка? И вообще, зачем вы показываете что пробовали для **коммента**. У вас с комментами проблема или с лайками? К тому же у вас уже и контроллеры есть для комментов, и все что надо, что вам мешает по аналогии сделать для лайков?

Comment: @tym32167 1) ну код не работает.  2) я не понимаю до конца как это работает. А, логику like вообще не понимаю. Вроде нажал на кнопку, в базу прибавилось единичка, счётчик увеличился  на один. А как кодом написать не пойму.

Answer (score 0):

Спорим, в консоли появляются оба сообщения?

```
               success: console.log('все ок'),
               error: console.log('Ошибка во время отправки комментария')
```

Вот так

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log('все ок', data);
},
error: function() { 
  console.log('Ошибка во время отправки комментария', this);
}
```

Как соотносятся параметр `sendComment` `applicationUserId` и `'@Model.Description'`, который передается в `sendComment`?

Comment: В примере который я использовал сделано так`'@post.Id', '@Model.User.Id'` но как мне прикрутить данные с моих моделей не пойму.

Comment: @EugeneTM Я ничего не знаю про "пример, который Вы использовали". А вижу только код в вопросе. Он неправильный.

Comment: Сейчас обновлю! Там всё логично. и мне нужно подогнать его под мои модели.